# Error "Failed to build gem native extension" while installing Jekyll

Tags: ruby, jekyll, fedora

I am trying to install Jekyll on Fedora 26 using the command `gem install jekyll --user-install`

But I receive the following error:

```
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing jekyll:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: /my_user/.gem/ruby/2.4.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser
/usr/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20180420-21754-1k1q01a.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/share/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /my_user/.gem/ruby/2.4.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /my_user/.gem/ruby/2.4.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.4.0/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/gem_make.out
```

I have Ruby installed:

```
ruby 2.4.3p205 (2017-12-14 revision 61247) [x86_64-linux]
```

And also I updated the Ruby Gems using `gem update --system`.

I searched the Stackoverflow, and I found a similar question solved for MacOS.

The output of `gem env` is as follows:

```
RubyGems Environment:
RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.7.6
RUBY VERSION: 2.4.3 (2017-12-14 patchlevel 205) [x86_64-linux]
INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /my_user/.gem/ruby/2.4.0
USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /my_user/.gem/ruby/2.4.0
RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby
EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /my_user/bin
SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /my_user/.gem/specs
SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /etc
RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
  ruby
  x86_64-linux
GEM PATHS:
   /my_user/.gem/ruby/2.4.0
   /usr/share/gems
  /usr/local/share/gems
GEM CONFIGURATION:
  :update_sources => true
  :verbose => true
  :backtrace => false
  :bulk_threshold => 1000
REMOTE SOURCES:
  https://rubygems.org/
SHELL PATH:
  /my_user/anaconda2/bin
  /my_user/anaconda2/bin
  /usr/libexec/python2-sphinx
  /usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin
  /my_user/perl5/bin
  /usr/local/bin
  /usr/bin
  /bin
  /usr/local/sbin
  /usr/sbin
  /usr/libexec/sdcc
  /my_user/.local/bin
  /my_user/bin
  /usr/libexec/sdcc
```

Comment: What happens if you just do `gem install jekyll` ?

Comment: The same error appears.

Comment: paste output of  `gem env` and have a look at https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/1948

Comment: The output of `gem env` is now added to the question.

Comment: See if you have make. `which make`, and if not, can you try `sudo yum install make` ?

Comment: I have make installed `/usr/bin/make`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There have been a few other posts regarding problems with older versions of Fedora and jekyll,  here's one:  https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/91815/problem-installing-jekyll-in-fedora-24/

Perhaps try:

```
sudo dnf install ruby-devel
gem install jekyll
```

or as per https://linuxsuperuser.com/install-jekyll-on-fedora-23/

```
sudo dnf install ruby-devel  
sudo dnf install redhat-rpm-config
sudo gem install jekyll
```